# From trivariate cdf to the distribution of differences of random variables

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable

Consider a trivariate cumulative distribution function (cdf) $G$.

- Is there a collection of ***necessary*** conditions on $G$ ensuring that
  $$
  \exists \text{ a random vector $(X_1,X_2)$ such that $(X_1, X_2, X_1-X_2)$ has cdf $G$}
  $$
  ?
- Is there a collection of ***necessary and sufficient*** conditions on $G$ ensuring that
  $$
  \exists \text{ a random vector $(X_1,X_2)$ such that $(X_1, X_2, X_1-X_2)$ has cdf $G$}
  $$
  ?

---

**Update I:** Let $P$ be the probability distribution associated with $G$. We can claim that: **if** there exists a random vector $(X_1,X_2)$ such that $(X_1, X_2, X_1-X_2)$ has probability distribution $P$, **then**
$$
\int_{(a,b,c)\in \mathbb{R}^3 \text{ s.t. } c=a-b} dP=1
$$

- Is this condition also sufficient? I.e., can we claim that **if** 
  $$
  \int_{(a,b,c)\in \mathbb{R}^3 \text{ s.t. } c=a-b} dP=1
  $$
  **then** 
  there exists a random vector $(X_1,X_2)$ such that $(X_1, X_2, X_1-X_2)$ has probability distribution $P$?
- Can we write
  $$
  \int_{(a,b,c)\in \mathbb{R}^3 \text{ s.t. } c=a-b} dP=1
  $$
  by using the cdf $G$
  ?

---

**Update II:**

**If** there exists a random vector $(X_1,X_2)$ such that $(X_1, X_2, X_1-X_2)$ has probability distribution $P$, **then** $P$ should satisfy:  for every $\begin{pmatrix}
a_1\\
b_1\\
c_1
\end{pmatrix}\leq \begin{pmatrix}
a_2\\
b_2\\
c_2
\end{pmatrix}$

- If $a_2\geq b_2+c_2$
  $$
  \begin{cases}
  P([a_1,a_2], [b_1, b_2], [c_1, c_2])= P([a_1, b_2+c_2], [b_1, b_2], [c_1, c_2])\\
  P([a_2, a_3], [b_1, b_2], [c_1, c_2])= 0  & \forall a_3\geq a_2\\
  \end{cases}
  $$
- If $b_1\leq a_1-c_2$
  $$
  \begin{cases}
  P([a_1,a_2], [b_1, b_2], [c_1, c_2])= P([a_1,a_2], [a_1-c_2, b_2], [c_1, c_2])\\
  P([a_1,a_2], [b_3, b_1], [c_1, c_2])=0 & \forall b_3\leq b_1\\
  \end{cases}
  $$
- If $a_1 \leq b_1+c_1$
  $$
  \begin{cases}
  P([a_1,a_2], [b_1, b_2], [c_1, c_2])= P([b_1+c_1,a_2],[b_1,b_2],[c_1,c_2])\\
  P([a_3,a_1], [b_1, b_2], [c_1, c_2])=0 & \forall a_3 \leq a_1
  \end{cases}
  $$
- If $b_2\geq a_2-c_1$
  $$
  \begin{cases}
  P([a_1,a_2], [b_1, b_2], [c_1, c_2])= P([a_1,a_2], [b_1, a_2-c_1], [c_1, c_2])\\
  P([a_1,a_2], [b_2, b_3], [c_1, c_2])=0 & \forall b_3\geq b_2
  \end{cases}
  $$
- If $c_2 \geq a_2-b_1$
  $$
  \begin{cases}
  P([a_1,a_2], [b_1, b_2], [c_1, c_2])= P([a_1,a_2], [b_1, b_2], [c_1, a_2-b_1])\\
  P([a_1,a_2], [b_1, b_2], [c_2, c_3])=0 & \forall  c_3\geq c_2
  \end{cases}
  $$
- If $c_1\leq a_1-b_2$
  $$
  \begin{cases}
  P([a_1,a_2], [b_1, b_2], [c_1, c_2])= P([a_1,a_2], [b_1, b_2], [a_1-b_2, c_2])\\
  P([a_1,a_2], [b_1, b_2], [c_3, c_1])=0 & \forall  c_3\leq c_1
  \end{cases}
  $$
  These implications can be written using $G$ (as I want!). However: are these implications also sufficient? I don't know how to prove or dis-prove it.

Comment: You have supplied such conditions: to wit, when $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ is a random variable with distribution $G,$ then almost surely $X_3=X_1-X_2.$  That's dead simple.  What other form are you hoping to express these conditions in that would be any simpler or more useful?

Comment: Thanks. I'm hoping for conditions directly imposed on $G$.

Answer (score 0):

The condition in your first update is sufficient, because it implies that $X_3=X_1-X_2$ almost surely, so in particular $(X_1,X_2,X_3)=^d(X_1,X_2,X_1-X_2)$.

Edit: To be completely explicit about the dependence of $G$, this can be restated by requiring that $P(B)=0$ for any 3-dimensional box $B$ such that $B\cap \{(x,y,z):z=x-y\}=\emptyset$.

Comment: Thanks. What about update II? Remember that I'm looking for conditions that can expressed using $G$.

Comment: The measure $dP$ is defined in terms of $G$, so I'm not sure what else you want.

Comment: I want necessary and sufficient conditions explicitly involving  "boxes" in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: Thanks. I think that "$P(B)=0$ for any 3-dimensional box $B$ such that $B\cap ...=\emptyset$" holds IF AND ONLY IF the bullet points in my update II hold. Is this correct?